# dependency Injection by annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I am a new user of spring. I am trying to achieve dependency injection by annotation. My 
beans.xml is :-

```
<!-- Add your classes base package here -->          
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springaction.chapter01"/>

<bean id="greeting" class="com.springaction.chapter01.GreetingImpl">
    <property name="greeting">
        <value>Naveen Jakad</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

bean which I want to inject is:-

```
package com.springaction.chapter01;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class InjectBean {

private int id;
private String name;

public InjectBean() {
    super();
}
//setter getter of above instance variables..
}
```

and the bean in which I want to inject above bean is :-

```
package com.springaction.chapter01;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class GreetingImpl implements Greeting {

private String greeting;

@Autowired
private InjectBean myBean;

public GreetingImpl() {
    super();
}
public GreetingImpl(String greeting) {
    super();
    this.greeting = greeting;
}

public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
    this.greeting = greeting;
}

@Override
public void sayGreeting() {
    System.out.println(greeting + " " + myBean);
}
}
```

so when I test the above code by :-

```
BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("config.xml"));
        Greeting greeting = (Greeting)beanFactory.getBean("greeting");
        greeting.sayGreeting();
```

I get the output "Naveen Jakad null", means in nutshell I am not able to achieve my target. So please help me out and let me know where I making mistake

Answer (score 3):

if you want to inject by @Autowired you don't need to config it in xml :)

You need to set

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.base.package" />
```

That way spring will know to check for annotations

Answer (score 0):

With Fixus solution you do not need the xml file where you define the "greeting" bean:

Just add:

```
@Component // or @Service if it's also a service
public class GreetingImpl implements Greeting {
```

This way you do not need to define your beans in the xml file.

If you use Junit test, you just inject the class to test (e.g "Greeting") in your MyJunitClass and have your context set to the one with the annotation-driven and component -scan definition.

You can see that doc to configure your JUnit tests:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations